# See contents of valarray<double> in CLion's debugger?

Tags: debugging, watch, clion, valarray

Is it possible to do something to easily see the contents of a `valarray<double>` in Clion's debugger?

Answer (score 1):

According to JetBrains ([1](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/02/clion-eap-news-cmake-3-1-stl-renderers-in-debugger-pty-and-more/#more-258)), if using GCC compiler you'll be able to inspect the STL containers during your debug session. In case of Clang it would work for libstdc++ only so you have to set the *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* in *CMakeLists.txt* to use it:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS “${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libstdc++”)
```

Comment: Note that I can inspect the contents of `vector<double>` without problems. It's `valarray<double>` that gives me trouble.

Comment: I've never starred at valarray values in debugger but now that you mention it, I gave it a try and got the same result i guess: I can see valarray's size but not the data. Have you tried by disabling all kind of compiler optimizations while Debugging?

Comment: How can I disable optimizations in CLion?

Comment: On what platform are you developing? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. GCC.